# google search web scraping class= not same as on browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

I am trying to grab video panel in google result
for example I am searching --->   "great+castles"  <--
and in that search result, it has a panel that contains videos
when I scrape it I get HTML but with different values of attributes
I am not able to grab video panel

```
text="great+castles"
url = f'https://google.com/search?q={text}'
response = requests.get(url)


print(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

a=soup.findAll('div',{'id':'main'})
a
```

I do get output response but attributes are not same as on google chrome

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can always write that HTML response in HTML file and check what actually you're getting by opening in the browser.

Secondly, you cannot **scrape** data from google that easily, you need proxies for that but even with elite proxies you may face number of challenges like reCaptcha etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to check source code returned by requests:

1. Save response as `html` file locally and open it in browser.
2. Get [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) framework and use `view(response)` from `Scrapy Shell`. The Scrapy option is handy but requires installation of the framework that can be an overkill for a one-time project.

There is also another(more robust) way to get results from Google Search by using [`Google Search API][2]` from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.
For example, your request will return handy json including the `inline video` section:

```
>     "inline_videos":
>     [
>     {
>     "position":
>     1,
>     "title":
>     "A Thousand Years of European Castles",
>     "link":
>     "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXSFt-zey84",
>     "thumbnail":
>     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uXSFt-zey84/mqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEECHwQRg&rs=AMzJL3n1trdIa7_n5X-kJf8pq70OYoY47w",
>     "channel":
>     "Best Documentary",
>     "duration":
>     "53:59",
>     "platform":
>     "YouTube",
>     "date":
>     "Jan 25, 2022"
>     },
>     {
>     "position":
>     2,
>     "title":
>     "The Most Beautiful Castles in the World",
>     "link":
>     "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln-v2ibnWHU",
>     "thumbnail":
>     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ln-v2ibnWHU/mqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEECHwQRg&rs=AMzJL3kHM2n3_vkRLM_stMr0XuiFs5uaCQ",
>     "channel":
>     "Luxury Homes",
>     "duration":
>     "4:58",
>     "platform":
>     "YouTube",
>     "date":
>     "Mar 29, 2020"
>     },
>     {
>     "position":
>     3,
>     "title":
>     "Great Castles of Europe: Neuschwanstein (Part 1 of 3)",
>     "link":
>     "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_uFzANW2Xo",
>     "thumbnail":
>     "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/R_uFzANW2Xo/mqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEECHwQRg&rs=AMzJL3nYdSY5YW2QU1pijXo3xx7ObrILdg",
>     "channel":
>     "trakehnen",
>     "duration":
>     "8:51",
>     "platform":
>     "YouTube",
>     "date":
>     "Sep 24, 2009"
>     }
>     ],
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape Google Search Video Panel Results using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library.

To get to the tab we need, you need to register it in the [`parameters`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), like this:

```py
# this URL params is taken from the actual Google search URL
# and transformed to a more readable format
params = {
   "q": "great castles",   # query
    "tbm" : "vid",         # video panel
    "gl": "us",            # contry of the search  
    "hl": "en"             # language of the search
}
```

To get the required data, you need to get a "container", which is a CSS selector called [class selector](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) that contains all the information about video results i.e title, link, channel name and so on.

In our case, this is the "video-voyager" selector which contains data about the title, channel name, video link, description and so on.

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser (*not always work perfectly if the website is rendered via JavaScript*).

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-google-search-video-panel#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, json

  
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
   "q": "great castles",   # query
    "tbm" : "vid",         # video panel
    "gl": "us",            # contry of the search  
    "hl": "en"             # language of the search
}

# by default it will scrape video page results but can be truned off
def scrape_google_videos(inline_videos=False, video_page=True):
    if inline_videos:
        data_inline_video = []
        
        params.pop("tbm", None) # deletes tbm: vid

        html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params, timeout=30)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
        
        print("Inline video data:\n") 
        for result in soup.select(".WZIVy"):
            title = result.select_one(".cHaqb").text
            platform = result.select_one("cite").text
            chanel = result.select_one(".pcJO7e span").text.replace(" · ", "")
            date = result.select_one(".hMJ0yc span").text
        
        
            data_inline_video.append({
              "title" : title,
              "platform" : platform,
              "chanel" : chanel,
              "date" : date
              })

        print(json.dumps(data_inline_video, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
        
    if video_page:
        data_video_panel = []
        
        html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params, timeout=30)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
        
        print("Video panel data:\n")
        for products in soup.select("video-voyager"):
            title = products.select_one(".DKV0Md").text
            description = products.select_one(".Uroaid").text
            link = products.select_one(".ct3b9e a")["href"] 
            chanel = products.select_one(".Zg1NU+ span").text
            duration = products.select_one(".J1mWY div").text
            date = products.select_one(".P7xzyf span span").text
               
            data_video_panel.append({
              "title" : title,
              "description" : description,
              "link" : link,
              "chanel" : chanel,
              "duration" : duration,
              "date" : date
            })
            
        print(json.dumps(data_video_panel, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

scrape_google_videos(video_page=True, inline_videos=False)
```

```json
Inline video data:

[
  {
    "title": "A Thousand Years of European Castles",
    "platform": "YouTube",
    "chanel": "Best Documentary",
    "date": "Jan 25, 2022"
  },
  {
    "title": "MOST BEAUTIFUL Castles on Earth",
    "platform": "YouTube",
    "chanel": "Top Fives",
    "date": "Feb 2, 2022"
  },
  {
    "title": "Great Castles of Europe: Neuschwanstein (Part 1 of 3)",
    "platform": "YouTube",
    "chanel": "trakehnen",
    "date": "Sep 24, 2009"
  }
]
```